# Why is the subspace of uniformly rho continuous functions separable?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, separable-spaces, empirical-processes

I am reading through the book of Kosorok on Empirical Processes and I got stuck on a statement that seems to be clear to the author. To me, it is not clear at all.

In chapter 6.1 page 87 he states that the subspace $UC(T,\rho)$ of $l^{\infty}(T)$ is a Polish space. In this case, $l^{\infty}(T)$ is equipped with the supremum norm and $\rho$ is a semimetric on the arbitrary set $T$ and $UC(T,\rho):=\{ f: T\mapsto \mathbb{R} \mid f\ \text{is bounded and uniformly $\rho- $continuous}\}$.

I understand,why the space is complete w.r.t. the uniform metric, but not why it is separable. 
It is also not clear to me if this statement refers to the case of $T$ being compact. In neither case I am able to deduce the separability of $UC(T,\rho)$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How can this be true?  What if $T = \mathbb N$ with the absolute value metric?  Then every member of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ is uniformly continuous, but $\ell^\infty$ is not separable.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is an arbitrary set, $\ell^\infty(T)$ is not separable. Taking $T=\mathbb{N}$ already fails this. And if we take $\rho$ the discrete metric, $UC(T,\rho) = \ell^\infty(T)$ is also not separable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess, the statement is not very clear on the properties of $T$. If we assume that $(T,\rho)$ is a compact space, would this imply separability? I know that $T$ is separable in this case (w.r.t.to $\rho$), but I cannot make the connection to $UC(T,\rho)$.

Comment: @FlorianBrück for a compact metric $T$ we do get separability by Weierstrass theorems.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly looks like what I am looking for. However, $(T,\rho)$ is not necessarily Haussdorff, since $\rho$ is only a semimetric, which is a requirement in the Stone-Weierstrass theorem (at leat the ones I know).

Comment: @FlorianBrück take a quotient with the same function space that is Hausdorff space. A standard technique.

Comment: Okay, the author did not mention that he wants to identify every element with its equivalence class, but I suspect that he just forgot about. Thank you very much! Its clear to me now.